# Build a Property List from a JSON Object c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to build the property list including property path of a json object.

I don't know the structure of the json or the keys that might be present. I'm after the keys at all levels (not the values of those keys).

```
 {
  "Primitive_1": "T1",
  "Object_L1": {
    "Object_L2": {
      "Object_L3": {
        "Object_L4": {
          "Object_L5": {
            "Object_L6": {
              "Array_L7": [
                {
                  "asdasdas": "SampleText1",
                  "WIDTH": "Width2"
                },
                {
                  "gh45gdfg": "SampleText2",
                  "WIDTH": "Width"
                }
              ],
              "12836hasvdkl": "SampleText3",
              "WIDTH": "Width"
            }
          }
        },
        "712bedfabsmdo98": "SampleText4",
        "WIDTH": "Width"
      }
    },
    "ALIAS_ID": 1
  },
  "Primitive_2": "T2",
  "Primitive_3": "T3",
  "Primitive_4": "T4"
}
```

Desired output:

```
.Primitive_1 .Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.Object_L4.Object_L5.Object_L6.Array_L7.0.asdasdas
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.Object_L4.Object_L5.Object_L6.Array_L7.0.WIDTH
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.Object_L4.Object_L5.Object_L6.Array_L7.1.gh45gdfg
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.Object_L4.Object_L5.Object_L6.Array_L7.1.WIDTH
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.Object_L4.Object_L5.Object_L6.12836hasvdkl
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.Object_L4.Object_L5.Object_L6.WIDTH
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.712bedfabsmdo98
.Object_L1.Object_L2.Object_L3.WIDTH
.Object_L1.ALIAS_ID
.Primitive_2
.Primitive_3
.Primitive_4
```

Having looked around I've gotten as far as the root nodes of the object. See fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/wIl1Qw)

This seems to be relatively simple in JS (http://jsfiddle.net/alteraki/bt3zc1wt/) I've already reviewed several responses and I can't find a response in c# that solves this problem without knowing the keys in use (which I don't know)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: NO FIDDLES post your code in the question. Also look here: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: You need to [use recursion](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b5AsCs).

Comment: @Phylogenesis - You're a life saver! Can you post as an answer as well then I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tree traversal algorithms are almost always recursive in nature.

As such, the following function does what you want:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetMembers(JToken jToken)
{
    var members = new List<string>();

    if (jToken is JObject)
    {
        var jObject = (JObject)jToken;

        foreach (var prop in jObject.Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Value is JValue)
            {
                members.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                members.AddRange(GetMembers(prop.Value).Select(member => prop.Name + "." + member));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (jToken is JArray)
    {
        var jArray = (JArray)jToken;

        for (var i = 0; i < jArray.Count; i++)
        {
            var token = jArray[i];

            members.AddRange(GetMembers(token).Select(member => i + "." + member));
        }
    }

    return members;
}
```

An example of the code running is available [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b5AsCs).